Apps installed through Flatpak not showing up
When I install a app through Flatpak the app installs, however you can only open it through the terminal.
Like this, flatpak run org.gnome.World.PikaBackup
I know there is a post about this, but is there possibly a more simple options?
Like a setting or a command that helps with this? I want my Flatpak apps to show up in the dock.

Does this issue still occur after rebooting?

what steps were taken to install Flatpak? [edit] in to your question. You may find this article helpful

Maybe you can try to add the program to favorites by following steps.

Open the program by entering the command flatpak run org.gnome.World.PikaBackup in the terminal. The program instance shall appear in the dock if it works fine.
Right click on the instance in the dock and click "Add to Favorites".
Since then, you can open the program simply by clicking the icon in the dock.

ps. I use flatpak for installing bottles. This is the way I open bottles.

Thank you so so much. You don't even know how much this helps me, I thought I was going crazy.
